# C++ sort pair with respect to two criteria

Tags: c++, sorting

I have the following `vector` with pair values:

```
first 3  second 2
first 1  second 2
first 1  second 1
first 2  second 2
```

I would like to sort my vector such that the result would be

```
==========================
first 1  second 2
first 1  second 1
first 2  second 2
first 3  second 2
```

That means:

- sort with respect to the first element.
- in case of equality sort with respect to the second element

My code looks like:

```
#include <utility>      // std::pair
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<double, double> my_pair;
struct sort_pred
{
      bool operator () (const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right)
            {
                  return (left.first < right.first) && (left.second > right.second);
            }
};

int main () {
      std::vector<my_pair> data;
      data.push_back(my_pair(3,2) );
      data.push_back(my_pair(1,2) );
      data.push_back(my_pair(1,1) );
      data.push_back(my_pair(2,2) );

      for(auto a: data)
            std::cout << "first "<< a.first << "  second " << a.second << std::endl;

      std::cout << "==========================\n";
      std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), sort_pred());  
      for(auto a: data)
            std::cout << "first "<< a.first << "  second " << a.second << std::endl;

      return 0;
}
```

The condition in the `sort_pred` expressed what I would like to do, but is not correct. I get wrong values.

Any idea how this can be *easily* solved?

Comment: The current condition considers, for example, `(1, 2)` and `(1, 1)` equivalent. You need `left.first < right.first || left.second < right.second`.

Answer (score 7):

Your comparator isn't quite right, since you want it to return `true` if either the first check succeeds OR the first are equal and the second check succeeds. You only want to check the `second`s if the `first`s are equal. So something like this:

```
struct sort_pred
{
    bool operator()(const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right) const
    {
        if (left.first != right.first) {
            return left.first < right.first;
        }
        return left.second > right.second;
    }
};
```

This can be simplified using the fact that `tuple`s are lexicographically comparable:

```
struct sort_pred
{
    bool operator()(const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right) const
    {
        return std::tie(left.first, right.second) < 
               std::tie(right.first, left.second);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a bit of tweaking to your predicate:

```
struct sort_pred
{
    bool operator () (const my_pair& lhs, const my_pair& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.first<rhs.first || 
               (!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second>rhs.second);
    }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd734b9d3229859e)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of && doesn't really make sense.  It goes on to evaluate the second element if `left.first > right.first`, but really you want that to only happen if `left.first == right.first`.

This should work:

```
  bool operator () (const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right)
        {
              if (left.first != right.first)
                  return left.first < right.first;
              else
                  return left.second > right.second;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish more cases:

```
bool operator () (const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right)
{
   if (left.first < right.first)
      return true;

   if (left.first != right.first)
      return false;

    // when primary criterion is equal:
    if (left.second > right.second) 
           // you want this to sort descending, right?
      return true;

    // .... other criteria

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your predicate is wrong ?

If I understand correctly, you want precedence on the first element, and only in case of equality on the second element?

so maybe something like:

```
struct sort_pred
{
     bool operator () (const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right)
           {
                 return (left.first == right.first) ? 
                        (left.second > right.second) : 
                        (left.first < right.first);
           }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want A to be before B if

- A first is less than B first, or
- If A first and B first are equal and B second is less than A second

In code that is

```
(a.first < b.first) or
((a.first == b.first) and
 (b.second < a.second))
```

But this is suboptimal, from a programming point of view: Now you need an additional `operator==` implemented.

But since a value can only be less, equal or greater than another, you can rewrite that to

```
(a.first < b.first) or
(not (b.first > a.first) and
 (b.second < a.second))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<double, double> my_pair;

struct sort_pred
{
    bool operator ()( const my_pair &left, const my_pair &right ) const
    {
        return ( left.first < right.first ) || 
               ( !( right.first < left.first ) && ( right.second < left.second ) );
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<my_pair> data;

    data.push_back( my_pair( 3, 2 ) );
    data.push_back( my_pair( 1, 2 ) );
    data.push_back( my_pair( 1, 1 ) );
    data.push_back( my_pair( 2, 2 ) );

    std::stable_sort( data.begin(), data.end(), sort_pred() );

    for ( const auto &p : data ) std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2
1 1
2 2
3 2
```